# Chrome not open deep linking react native android/iOS

Tags: react-native, ios-universal-links, applinks

I have configured deep linking on the react native project.

In iOS, it works on safari but when I open the link from Chrome it doesn't work.

In Android, it work when I test `db shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d ...` but I open with Chrome then it not working

Comment: Firebase deeplinking are you trying?

Comment: firebase's dynamic link works fine, but it only supports until 2025